# Placing an image in-line with text

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm trying to insert a small image inline with some text. A the moment I have my code like this:

```
Press \begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{fit_button}\end{figure} to start the fitting. Wait for the program to finish and the fit should
```

This results in

[image]

But I would like to have it be like this

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if it works:

```
Press \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{fit_button} to start the fitting. Wait 
for the program to finish and the fit should
```

#### Reason

`figure` is a floating environment, it always takes a new line even if the floating option is `H`. So of course we can't use `figure` here.

In fact, `\includegraphics{}` makes the picture like a normal character. Just place it "as usual".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including an image, this can be done in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Press \fcolorbox{black}{lightgray!50!white}{\textsf{\textbf{~~~FIT~~~}}} to start the fitting. Wait for the program to finish and the fit should

\end{document}
```

The advantage is that it will be easier to copy the text from the pdf

[image]